# Declare @MyVar SameAs [Table].[Column]

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

In the latest version of T-SQL, which I presume is SQL 2008 R2, can one declare a variable and specify that its type is to be the same as a specified table.column rather than hard coding a specific data type/length?

I'm guessing that T-SQL still doesn't have it but I wanted to be sure.

Comment: I don't believe you can do it that easily.  You'd have to use a bit of bulky dynamic SQL to get that end result.

Comment: The other thing you can do is create a user defined datatype. And declare the column and variable as that type. I don't recommend doing this though. If you ever need to tweak the definition it is painful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You can't.

It has been requested though on [MS Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/124506). Vote it up. And asked for [twice too](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/632548/declare-a-variable-of-a-type-that-of-a-column-in-table).